# search for unknown operator (bpy warning in custom script)

Tags: python

I'm calling one of my operators within another operator. The code worked fine until I tried it on a new file.

```
search for unknown operator 'MYPLUG_OT_update_list'
```

I'll try to simplify the code here

```
class login(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "myplug.login"
    bl_label = "Login"

    def execute(self,context):
        ....

        bpy.ops.myplugin.update_list()

        return {'FINISHED'}


class updateList(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "myplug.update_list"
    bl_label = "UpdateList"

    def execute(self,context):
        ....
        return {'FINISHED'}

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    register()
```

Any ideas? I'm debating whether I need to preregister the dependent Operator or call it with some other convention.

Comment: Are there any errors printed to the system console at registration time? A bad line of code in the operator class can let the registration of that class fail.

Comment: No. No other errors.

Comment: Well, it works fine for me. There must be something wrong, or the example code is different from your actual setup.

Comment: This is impossible to repo. Maybe I did have some other error.

Comment: @BenL still having problem with this ?

Comment: No. I've moved on. The issue may remain for someone else.

Answer (score 1):

The message:

```
search for unknown operator "NAME_TYPE_shortname", "NAME_TYPE_shortname"
```

could come from the user preferences keyboard shortcuts manager.

- Registering an incorrectly spelled operator path will give that message.
- Adding the shortcut in your script before the operator is registered will give that error too.

Maybe this is a typo but your

```
class updateList(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "myplug.update_list"
```

Would mean that the operator is located at `bpy.ops.myplug.update_list()`, not `bpy.ops.myplugin.*`

There is no inherent reason that operators can't be called within other operators, but you will have to wait for the called operator to complete before the calling operator can end, it doesn't fork off into its own thread.

for instance

```
import bpy

class login(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "myplug.login"
    bl_label = "Login"

    def execute(self,context):
        ...

        # bpy.ops.myplug.update_list()  # should be.  
        bpy.ops.myplugin.update_list()

        return {'FINISHED'}


class updateList(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "myplug.update_list"
    bl_label = "UpdateList"

    def execute(self,context):
        print('caramba!')
        return {'FINISHED'}

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    register()
    bpy.ops.myplug.login()


# AttributeError: Calling operator "bpy.ops.myplugin.update_list" error, could not be found
```

If you are calling a set of operators in sequence, then of course you must  ensure that the operators are registered globally. If i'm not mistaken the `bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)` will register classes in order of appearance in the file, use that order to your advantage.